# Can't show any thing with Layout, I want to know How to fix this problem that using Route with Layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-router-dom

before to change code I can show both HomeScreen and LoginScreen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

import Header from './components/header/Header'
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar'
import HomeScreen from './screens/homeScreen/HomeScreen'

import './_app.scss'

  const App = () => {
  const [sidebar, toggleSidebar] = useState(false)

  const handleToggleSidebar = () => toggleSidebar(value => !value)
  return (

     <>
        <Header handleToggleSidebar={handleToggleSidebar} />
        <div className="app__container">
           <Sidebar
              sidebar={sidebar}
              handleToggleSidebar={handleToggleSidebar}
           />
           <Container fluid className="app__main">
              <HomeScreen />
           </Container>




        </div>
     </>
  )
}

export default App
```

it's work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPYMH.png)

when I change code to Layout

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

import Header from './components/header/Header'
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar'
import HomeScreen from './screens/homeScreen/HomeScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/loginScreen/LoginScreen'

import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import './_app.scss'




const Layout = ({ children }) => {
   const [sidebar, toggleSidebar] = useState(false)

   const handleToggleSidebar = () => toggleSidebar(value => !value)

   return (
      <>
         <Header handleToggleSidebar={handleToggleSidebar} />
         <div className='app__container'>
            <Sidebar
               sidebar={sidebar}
               handleToggleSidebar={handleToggleSidebar}
            />
            <Container fluid className='app__main '>
               {children}
            </Container>
         </div>
      </>
   )
}




const App = () => {



  return (


      <Routes>
         <Route path='/' exact>
            <Layout>
               <HomeScreen />
            </Layout>
         </Route>

         <Route path='/auth'>
            <LoginScreen />
         </Route>

         <Route path='/search'>
            <Layout>
              <h1>asfaasfas</h1>
            </Layout>
         </Route>

         <Route>
            <Navigate to="/" />
         </Route>
      </Routes>

   )
}

export default App
```

It has no errors at all.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzpCP.png)

but nothing shows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQyDa.png)

...........................................................................

Comment: Unassigned lines in the question template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [React Router V6](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview), we render a component to a `Route` using the `element` prop.
[This answer from a similar post gives a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365093/when-i-apply-react-router-to-my-app-it-stops-showing-all-the-content/71365422#71365422).

You also need to wrap your App in a `BrowserRouter`. Assuming all your routes use the same layout, I'd recommend arranging your app is follows:

```
const App = () => {

    <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
            <Routes>
                <Routes path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} />
                ...
            </Routes>
        </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
}
```