# When I apply react router to my app, it stops showing all the content

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an app with react router, but when I try to apply the react router, it instantly stops showing all the content. I'm using V5 so Switch should work but it doesnt

Here is the code:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
     <Router>
         <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
        <Main />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/form">
          <Form />
        </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have setup your routes, but you aren't rendering any components.

With [React Router V6](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview), simply instansiate a React component inside the `element` prop on each `Route`:

```
...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
     <Router>
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/form" element={<Form />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
);
```

If you haven't already, I'd advice encapsulating each route into its own component to make this easier.

Comment: using the "element" attribute does the trick for me with react router V6, but the correct route declaration would look like <Route ... path="your path" element={<Your Component/>} />.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first go to the `index.js` or `main.jsx` file and wrap your App component with `BrowserRouter>` component.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
 </BrowserRouter>
```

or you can create routes here as the example below

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
    <Route path="compOne" element={<Component1 />} />
    <Route path="compTwo" element={<Component2 />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now you can use routes by using `Navlink` or `Link` components.

Comment: the requestor is using <Router/> already, which is a valid router according to docs.

Answer (score 0):

The route declaration I used to make it work with react router V6 looked like

`<Route path="/yourpath" element={<YourComponent/>} />`

So there should not be any closing tag </Route>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wrap up your app in the BrowserRouter provided by react-router-dom, that's the most probable cause.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).